# How to strip useless characters from utf-8 LIST

Tags: python-3.x

I have this following snippet.

```
def profile_details():  #function to fetch people
    payload = 'grab'
    global result_people 
    result_people = []
    for i in range(0,5):
        git_url = "https://github.com/search?p="+str(i)+"&q="+str(payload)+"&type=Users"
        rr = requests.get(git_url, headers=burp0_headers, cookies=burp0_cookies)
        page =  bs4.BeautifulSoup(rr.text,"lxml")
        page_parse = page.select('.user-list-info p')
        for i in range(len(page_parse)): 
                test = page_parse[i].text
                if ('@ Grab' in test) or ('at Grab' in test) or ('@Grab' in test)  or ('@grab' in test):
                        a = result_people.append(page_parse[i].text.encode("utf-8"))
                else:
                        pass

profile_details()
for i in result_people:
        print(i)
```

and the output looks something like this

```
[b'\n          Front End @facebook \xf0\x9f\x8c\x9d \xc2\xb7 Maintaining Docusaurus \xc2\xb7 Ex-@grab \xf0\x9f\x87\xb8\xf0\x9f\x87\xac\r\n\n        ', b'\n          Coding at Amazon, previously @Grab\n', b'\n          Software Engineer @grab \r\nPreviously @shopback \n        ', b'\n          Front End @facebook \xf0\x9f\x8c\x9d \xc2\xb7 Maintaining Docusaurus \xc2\xb7 Ex-@grab \xf0\x9f\x87\xb8\xf0\x9f\x87\xac\r\n\n        ', b'\n          Coding at Amazon, previously @Grab\n', b'\n          Software Engineer @grab \r\nPreviously @shopback \n        ', b'\n          UX Engineer @ Grab\n', b'\n          Designer at @Grab. Design Systems. Emerging tech (AR).\n        ', b'\n          Mobile Developer (iOS) @Grab. Previously Flipkart.\n        ', b'\n          Data science and engineering at Grab\n', b'\n          Software Engineer @ Grab.\n        ', b"\n          Finding top #talent for @Grab's #mobile #app development teams, software engineering, #iOS & #Android in #Singapore\n        ", b'\n          Frontend Software Engineer at Grab\n', b'\n          Developer @Grab(GrabTaxi)\n        ', b'\n          Full Stack - Software Engineer @ Grab | AI Enthusiast\n        ', b'\n          Software Engineer at Grab\n', b'\n          Software Engineer @Grab | Previous @udacity @disney | Open Source nut, right now juggling with iOS and Swift\n        ', b'\n          Ex-Engineering Lead @grab, Ex-DoE @90seconds\n        ', b'\n          Software Engineer/ Gopher. Worked @grab, @microsoft\n        ']
```

I want to strip characters  such as \xf0\x9f\x8c\x9d \ from the list.

Output seems like a mess :

```
b'\n          Front End @facebook \xf0\x9f\x8c\x9d \xc2\xb7 Maintaining Docusaurus \xc2\xb7 Ex-@grab \xf0\x9f\x87\xb8\xf0\x9f\x87\xac\r\n\n        '
```

b'\n          Coding at Amazon, previously @Grab\n'
b'\n          Software Engineer @grab \r\nPreviously @shopback \n        '
b'\n          Front End @facebook \xf0\x9f\x8c\x9d \xc2\xb7 Maintaining Docusaurus \xc2\xb7 Ex-@grab \xf0\x9f\x87\xb8\xf0\x9f\x87\xac\r\n\n        '
b'\n          Coding at Amazon, previously @Grab\n'
b'\n          Software Engineer @grab \r\nPreviously @shopback \n        '

What can be  the  easiest and convenient way to achieve this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

You can do it by removing all non-ASCII characters from each string

```
for i in result_people:
    print(i.decode('utf8').encode('ascii', errors='ignore'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it by ignoring the error while encoding in ascii by using ignore as an argument & then convert it back to utf-8.

```
result_people.append(page_parse[i].text.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode("utf-8"))
```